# How to upload files to db instead root directory?

Tags: python, django

I have a project in django, i am trying to upload files by an API and save those files in my db but the files are saved in my db and on my ROOT DIRECTORY and i don't want that.

POSTMAN API, i select a file, in this case i select "ejemplobionario.txt"

[image]

Then i go to Visual Studio Code and the file "ejemplobinario.txt" is there

[image]

I don't want it to be in my root directory, i just want it to be inside database. Please help me!

**serializers.py**

```
class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta():
      model = File
      fields = ('file', 'remark', 'timestamp')
```

**models.py**

```
class File(models.Model):
   file = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)
   remark = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**views.py**

```
class FileView(APIView):
parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
file_serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.data)
if file_serializer.is_valid():
  file_serializer.save()
  
  return Response(file_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
else:
  return Response(file_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Well, you can't save a file into a database.  You can save the NAME of a file, or the CONTENTS of a file into a database.  What is it you want?

Comment: I'd like to test with both, could you give me examples of how to save the name and how to save the contents please?

Comment: Have you looked in your database to see what you get?  I assume you're already saving the file name.  The Django `FileField` object that you are using has a an `upload_to` parameter that lets you specify a directory to hold the data, or a function that will receive the file object.  You could use that function to read the data into a database field.  You have to know what you want.

Comment: Yes, i do a select and i get the file name too. It gets added to the bd and the directory :/ . I don't understand how to use the upload to parameter in FileField to save my files in bd only , could you give me an example please?

Comment: It's not normal to store the contents in the database. If a malicious user uploaded a gigabyte file, your database would explode.  It looks like the Django `FileField` doesn't handle this case.  You'd have to have a plain text field, and then modify your view to handle the file upload yourself.